# Reading CSV file with Spark runs sometimes forever

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

i'm using `Spark 2.4.8` with the `gcs-connector` from `com.google.cloud.bigdataoss` in version `hadoop2-2.1.8`. For development i'm using a Compute Engine VM with my IDE. I try to consume some CSV files from a GCS bucket natively with the Spark `.csv(...).load(...)` functionality. Some files are loaded successfully, but some are not. Then in the Spark UI i can see that the load job runs forever until a timeout fires.

But the weird thing is, that when i run the same application packaged to a Fat-JAR in Dataproc cluster, all the same files can be consumed successfully.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Does this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197811/can-i-read-csv-files-from-google-storage-using-spark-in-more-than-one-executor/61209050#61209050) help? Can you provide sample code/command you are using?

Comment: Hi @JanOels, Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Hi, yes, with gcs-connector in version hadoop2-2.2.8 the files can be written in the IDEA too. Strange, but yeah, it's resolved.

Comment: Hi @JanOels, I have posted the answer as Community wiki. So If my answer addressed your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JanOels, As you have mentioned in the comment, using gcs-connector in version hadoop2-2.2.8 will resolve this issue and the latest version of hadoop2 is `hadoop2-2.2.10`.

For more information about all the versions of hadoop2 to use `gcs-connector` from `com.google.cloud.bigdataoss` this [document](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.google.cloud.bigdataoss%20AND%20a:gcs-connector%20AND%20v:hadoop2-*) can be referred.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.